# .pem file was unable to be decoded by google developer support system

Tags: android, android-studio, keytool, google-play-console

Back in the day we used to release our app as an apk in our own website. But recently we decided to publish our android application in google play. So we created an account and published our app there. Buy unfortunately when I was creating the release I didn't pay attention carefully. So I chose the wrong option. I mean I should have selected the Advanced option and provide my own specific key. but I just clicked continue.

[image]

So Google manages and protect app signing key and therefore the signature of the release in the google play is now different from the one that I release in my own website. Recently, I tried to change the private key to be used for signing the app in google play. I contacted google play developer support. After they verified my account the sent me an email containing the following instructions:

> Now that we’ve verified your account, I’m happy to help you reset the upload key for your app, xxx. The new upload key will be used to sign APKs that you upload to Play.
>
> We recommend that you adjust your planning to include a buffer period of 48 hours from when the upload key has been reset before you can use the new upload key. You can learn more about using app signing by Google Play here.
>
> Here’s how to generate and register a new upload key:
>
> Follow the instructions in the Android Studio Help Center to generate a new key. It must be different from any previous keys. Alternatively, you can use the following command line to generate a new key:
>
> keytool -genkeypair -alias upload -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 9125 -keystore keystore.jks
>
> This key must be a 2048 bit RSA key and have 25-year validity.
> Export the certificate for that key to PEM format:
> keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
>
> Reply to this email and attach the upload_certificate.pem file.

They asked me to send them a .pem file. I didn't create a new keystore because I already had one. So I just used the `keytool` command to export my key to a pem file:

```
keytool -export -rfc -alias upload -file upload_certificate.pem -keystore keystore.jks
```

The command run successfully, ***But when I sent it to them they replied that the .pem file you provided was unable to be decoded by our system!***

- Could you please tell what am did I wrong, here?
- Is it possible to change the private key in google play console?

Thanks.

Comment: Maybe they had a problem with the RFC format? Can you try without -rfc and see if they can handle the binary version?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have asked Google support to reset the **upload key** not the **app signing key**, since they gave you instructions on how to generate an upload key (also, see the name of the file they ask you to send them), or possibly they misunderstood your request.

To change the app signing key, you have two options:

- If you don't have any external users on this app, you can request Google for your app to be deleted so that you can re-create your app with the same package name.
- If you already have external users, then deleting the app is obviously not an option but you can use the feature **Upgrade your app signing key for new installs**. See full documentation at https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423. Note that this feature was primarily introduced to upgrade the security of apps in the Play Store in case developers were stuck with old weak keys. One restriction of this feature is that you can only do this once in the lifetime of your app, so make sure that you want to do this.